# How to load two templates inside controller function?

Tags: symfony

I have a list.html.twig file in which I have included another template file like:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    {{ include('default/partials/groupSettings.html.twig') }}
</div>
```

And in my controller function following is given:

```
public function settingsListAction()
{
    $settingsGroup = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1SettingGroup')->findAll();

    return $this->render('default/settingsList.html.twig', array('settingsGroup' => $settingsGroup));

    $settingsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1Setting')->findAll();

    return $this->render('default/partials/groupSettings.html.twig', array('settingsList' => $settingsList));
}
```

But it only loading the first template and not the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

includes should be written like so :

```
{{ include('[BundleName]:[directory_with_your_template]:templatename.html.twig', { 'settingsGroup': settingsGroup }) }}
```

and in your controller you render only the parent template and pass the params you need to the child template

```
public function settingsListAction()
{
    $settingsGroup = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1SettingGroup')->findAll();
    $settingsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1Setting')->findAll();

    return $this->render('default/settingsList.html.twig', array('settingsGroup' => $settingsGroup, 'settingsList' => $settingsList));
}
```

Comment: {{ include('[AppBundle]:[default/partials]:templatename.html.twig', { 'settingsGroup': settingsGroup }) }} Is it correct?

Comment: remove the square brackets "[ ]"

Comment: Bundle:Subdir:filename.html.twig